# Showing Total with 2 Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, jquery, tofixed

I'm working on a restaurant online menu and need to show the total as customers add items to the menu. However, my total only updates with 1 decimal. I'm trying to use toFixed(2) but can't quite get it working.

```
var banquetPrice = parseInt($(document).find(".menuChoice").val());
$(".menuChoice").change(function () {
updateTotal()
});
var total = (banquetPrice * numGuests) + (9.25 * numGuac) + (9.25 * numQuesa) + (9.25 * numNachos)

$("#total").html(total);
total.toFixed(2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "My total updates only with 1 decimal", do you mean your `#total` element? You're not calling the `toFixed(2)` until *after* you set the html. Also, you need to set it to itself, like `total = total.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go buddy..

```js
var total = (12.35 * 5) + (9.25 * 1) + (9.25 * 1) + (9.25 * 1)

$("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
```

```css
label{
border-bottom : 2px solid green;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label id="total" ></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments above, you should be calling `total.toFixed(2)` on the same line that you update the text of your `#total` element. You currently discard the return value of `toFixed` instead of using it. Using the more performant `.text()` instead of `.html()`, that line now becomes:

```
$("#total").text(total.toFixed(2))
```

### Demo:

```js
$(".menuChoice").change(updateTotal)

updateTotal()

function updateTotal() {
  // Assuming that these variables are already
  // defined and set to meaningful values
  var numGuests = 1
  var numGuac = 1
  var numQuesa = 1
  var numNachos = 1
  
  var banquetPrice = +$(".menuChoice").val()
  var total = (banquetPrice * numGuests) + (9.25 * numGuac) + (9.25 * numQuesa) + (9.25 * numNachos)
  $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Menu Choice: <input class="menuChoice" value="0"/>
<p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p>
```